# Keep the item under the mouse during drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I actually use jQuery .draggable() method for drag some items.

My container is bigger than my window, so, i have a scrollbar on the right side, as usual. Now, if i want to drag an item from the top to the bottom, I need to click on it and scroll the mouse at the same time.

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/YLer3/ If you take the item and you start to scroll, the item stay at his first position, you need to move the mouse for bring it to it.

There is a way for keep the item under the mouse even if you scroll ?

Sample html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="draggableItm">
</div>
```

Sample css code:

```
.container{
    height:1650px;
}
 .draggableItm{
    background-color:red;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Sample jQuery code:

```
$('.draggableItm').draggable({
    grid:[20,20]
});
```

Comment: If you can figure out how to snap to a grid, you can figure out how to  auto-scroll: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-scroll

Comment: If you put your mouse bellow the window, up again, bellow it, up.. scrolls with it (just repeat it)

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug. As described in http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9379

you should change

```
if (!this.offset.scroll) {
```

by

```
if (!this.offset.scroll || scroll.scrollTop() != this.offset.scroll.top || scroll.scrollLeft() != this.offset.scroll.left) {
```

in the implementations of _convertPositionTo and _generatePosition in jquery.ui.draggable.js.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to give a css class like active to your currently dragging item.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('.draggableItm').css({
        'top': ($(document).scrollTop() + $('.draggableItm').height())+'px'
    });

    $('.summary').text($(document).scrollTop()+'px');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YLer3/1/